# localizing FineUploader "processing" message

Tags: localization, fine-uploader

I have managed to localise most of the fine uploader messages via the API and template. However I cannot find where the text "processing" is being added.
[image: file uploading]

I'm sure it's somewhere simple but can't find it. Can anyone help me out?

thanks

Comment: Glad you found your answer. By the way, looks like you're using either a very old version of Fine Uploader, or the legacy CSS file. You can make your uploader look a lot nicer without any effort just by switching to one of the gallery or the new standard CSS file. More details at http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/styling.html.

Comment: thanks Ray. Yes was using the old css. We were unsure whether or not to use the dropzone feature because we only want a simple single file only upload.  We were then going to style it in accordance with the site. Tried the newer css and it looks nice and it is good to have the dropzone. So may go with it.

Comment: Incidentally, before we found this we tried dropzone.js but didn't like the way it allowed the user to drop more than one file on the zone even though multi select was off. We prefer the way Fine Uploader handles this by preventing the drop in the first place.  We also have found Fine Uploader reliable when dropzone kept failing in the middle of an upload with no way to find out why. Dropzone.js support seems dead too. U get what you pay for :)

Comment: Yes, dropzone is an abandoned library of questionable quality, that is for sure. Glad I could help and glad Fine Uploader is working for you.

Answer (score 2):

I found it. waitingforResponse under text options.

```
text: {
         defaultResponseError: defaultResponseErrorMsg,
         fileInputTitle: fileInputTitleMsg,
         formatProgress: formatProgressMsg,
         waitingForResponse: "This is the place!"
     }
```

I was looking at the API options for the CORE (basic) version and I am using the UI version.